# Excel vba copy averaged amount of used rows to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset that will change every month.  The dataset needs to be divided up and assigned to staff for review.  The quantity of rows will vary from month to month, but not the columns.  I currently copy the data from the columns that are useful to the staff and put them in another sheet.  I would like to further separate the data by the average amount of employees, which does not change.  I have attached a couple of pictures to better illustrate what I would like to accomplish.  My vba will "select" the rows as sequenced the way I would like, but I cannot figure out how to move the data to sheet3, even using a modification of the code I used to move the data from sheet1 to sheet2.

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Sub runAll()
    Call fltrColumns
End Sub

Sub fltrColumns()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim avgRow As Long

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents    'Clears data on Sheet2

    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row    'Counts rows minus the header

    avgRow = lastRow / 9    'Average based on a constant of nine personnel

    'Copy specific data over to Sheet2
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E1:E" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1:F" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1:H" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1:I" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1:H" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1:L" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I1:I" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M1:M" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J1:J" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K1:K" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L1:L" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & lastRow).Value

    'Used to see if the values are calculating correctly
    'MsgBox lastRow
    'MsgBox avgRow

    staffAverage (avgRow)

End Sub

Sub staffAverage(ByVal avgRow As Long)

    Dim grpOne As Long
    Dim grpTwo As Long
    Dim grpThree As Long
    Dim grpFour As Long
    Dim grpFive As Long
    Dim grpSix As Long
    Dim grpSeven As Long
    Dim grpEight As Long
    Dim grpNine As Long

    grpOne = avgRow
    grpTwo = avgRow * 2
    grpThree = avgRow * 3
    grpFour = avgRow * 4
    grpFive = avgRow * 5
    grpSix = avgRow * 6
    grpSeven = avgRow * 7
    grpEight = avgRow * 8
    grpNine = avgRow * 9

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Cells(grpOne, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpOne, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpTwo, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpTwo, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpThree, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpThree, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpFour, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpFour, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpFive, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpFive, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpSix, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpSix, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpSeven, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpSeven, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpEight, 12)).Offset(1).Select
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(grpEight, 1).Offset(1), Cells(grpNine, 12)).Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer to [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-copy-method-excel) method. You can copy to another workbook if the Destination range is there.

Comment: @Patrick this will work when the used range is selected, isn't using "copy/paste" not the best method?  Additionally, I need the code to walk through the entire dataset on sheet2 and each averaged selection moved to its own new sheet, which I really need help with.

Comment: You should NOT use `Range.Select` unless you want visual to the user. You just need to `Set` source and destination ranges to use. You can create a loop to create new workbook, Copy-Paste the range to the new workbook, save it in Temp/Shared Folder/email it automatically.

Comment: @Patrick I agree, and that is what I would like.  I want a loop to walk through the dataset, the pictures/code above is mostly a visual example and my question is because I am stuck trying to get the values to different sheet.  What I am trying is not working.